# Read gridview cell values and text

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to read gridview  controls value or text. But it return null value. I can't find out. But the gridview having some record with the value. Please help me to solve this.

```
 GridViewRow row = null;
 for (int i = 0; i < grd.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
      row = grd.Rows[i];
      HiddenField file_id = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("FLD_ID");
      Label pack_name = (Label)row.FindControl("FLD_NAME");
      string text = file_id.Value;
      bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;

      if (isChecked)
      {
           //Here its comming
      }
  }
```

My partial gridview code here

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#93afba"
                                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="50" Width="100%" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="#93afba"
                                    Font-Size="14px">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <%--<asp:CheckBox ID="chkall" runat="server" OnChange="checkAll();" />--%>
                                                <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" onclick="CheckAll(this)" runat="server" />
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemStyle Width="20px" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FLD_ID" Visible="false">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="lbl_id" runat="server" Value='<%#Bind("FLD_ID") %>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NAME">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="lbl_packname" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FLD_NAME") %>' ></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: u r doing this in which event of gridview?

Comment: button click event inside of gridview or outside?

Comment: Is grid maintaining the state even after the button click?

Comment: u need to pass the id of the child control inside FindControl method. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you want to find ***Checkbox2*** and you are finding ***chkSelect***

please replace this

```
bool isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect")).Checked;
```

with

```
bool isChecked = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox)grd_proforma_bill.HeaderRow.FindControl("Checkbox2")).Checked;
```

Comment: K thank you so much.But the Label pack_name = (Label)grd_proforma_bill.Rows[i].FindControl("lbl_packname");   always return null., But it has some value.

Comment: in your code you written as Label pack_name = (Label)row.FindControl("FLD_NAME"); it should be Label pack_name = (Label)row.FindControl("lbl_packname");

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine.

if you are binding gridview on page load be sure your code is as below block

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //code to bind gridview
            }
```

Comment: yes am using this   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                load_grid();

Comment: share your gridview .aspx page code, may be viewstate is false

Answer (score 0):

> Change the code to and check:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grd_proforma_bill.Rows.Count; i++)  
{ 
  HiddenField file_id = (HiddenField)grd_proforma_bill.Rows[i].FindControl("lbl_id");  
  Label pack_name = (Label)grd_proforma_bill.Rows[i].FindControl("lbl_packname");  
  string text = file_id.Value;  
  CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)grd_proforma_bill.Rows[i].FindControl("Checkbox2"); 
  bool isChecked = cb.Checked;

  if (isChecked)  
  {  
       //Here its comming  
  }  
}
```

Comment: I checked that. It always return null.